# Windows 10 Workstation backup

Tags: windows-10, backup, time-machine, file-history

My need can be descibed as backing up selected forders by type, and the type of backup I am looking for is like File-History or Time-Machine. Basically, as a developer, I only want to backup the code files I create, I could care less about binaries. I want to backup only selected folders, and selected file types within those folders onto an external drive, continously and keep as many backups as the space will fit, purging by age when I run out of space.

Is there some way to achieve this with Windows File History, and if not, is there some other tool I can use? I am trying to avoid writting my own...

Comment: If you are really particular, you could use a batch file. I use them all the time to backup specific folders, omitting others, etc. You can specify what type of files to include and exclude. I would opt for "robocopy", which is built in to Windows. You would need to add a separate section that would do the purging part but that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called [SyncFolders](http://www.syncfolders.elementfx.com/) that can be very usefull for you.

You can specify the file types to copy and the exclusions rules too.

The files deleted or overwritten can be moved to the recycle bin or to a time-stamped history folder and history files can be deleted after a user-defined period.